# How to get table headers and table data from a table row together in list?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the data in the table row into one list, but some of it is a table header and some of it is table data, unsure how to grab them both.

This is for Python 3.7 using bs4

```
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abrinal01.html'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('#per_game')

table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "per_game" })
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I can get all of the table data into a list, so everything right of the first column but not the data in the first columns themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the headers in your data, you can combine the output of `find_all('td')` with  `find_all('th')`. Is this what you want?

```py
import requests, bs4

url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abrinal01.html'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
elems = soup.select('#per_game')

table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "per_game" })
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('th') + tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

Produces this output:

```
['Season', 'Age', 'Tm', 'Lg', 'Pos', 'G', 'GS', 'MP', 'FG', 'FGA', 'FG%', '3P', '3PA', '3P%', '2P', '2PA', '2P%', 'eFG%', 'FT', 'FTA', 'FT%', 'ORB', 'DRB', 'TRB', 'AST', 'STL', 'BLK', 'TOV', 'PF', 'PTS']
['2016-17', '23', 'OKC', 'NBA', 'SG', '68', '6', '15.5', '2.0', '5.0', '.393', '1.4', '3.6', '.381', '0.6', '1.4', '.426', '.531', '0.6', '0.7', '.898', '0.3', '1.0', '1.3', '0.6', '0.5', '0.1', '0.5', '1.7', '6.0']
['2017-18', '24', 'OKC', 'NBA', 'SG', '75', '8', '15.1', '1.5', '3.9', '.395', '1.1', '2.9', '.380', '0.4', '0.9', '.443', '.540', '0.5', '0.6', '.848', '0.3', '1.2', '1.5', '0.4', '0.5', '0.1', '0.3', '1.7', '4.7']
['2018-19', '25', 'OKC', 'NBA', 'SG', '31', '2', '19.0', '1.8', '5.1', '.357', '1.3', '4.1', '.323', '0.5', '1.0', '.500', '.487', '0.4', '0.4', '.923', '0.2', '1.4', '1.5', '0.6', '0.5', '0.2', '0.5', '1.7', '5.3']
['Career', '', '', 'NBA', '', '174', '16', '16.0', '1.8', '4.5', '.387', '1.3', '3.4', '.368', '0.5', '1.1', '.443', '.525', '0.5', '0.6', '.880', '0.3', '1.1', '1.4', '0.5', '0.5', '0.1', '0.4', '1.7', '5.3']
```

Comment: Yes!! I just had to move the `tr.find_all('th')` in front of the  `tr.find_all('td')`. Thank you so much.